# Successfull transaction stucked because of blocks confirmation not stopping

Tags: etherscan, blocks, confirmations

5 hours a go I did a transaction on ERC20 from kucoin to a wallet. Kucoin says it successfull, Ethercan also successfull but the confirmation blocks keep increasing more than 1500 as I wrote this message. Does someone know how to end it or if it's not possible, how long it could take ?
Take you in advance
B.

Comment: Blocks are always produced, that the whole purpose of a blockchain. It shouldn't matter more blocks are created once the transaction was confirmed.